# Ajax get request for URL never successful

Tags: ajax, jquery

Hey guys I have the following ajax request.

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",   
     url: "http://alpha.mywebsite.com/test.html",   
     async: false,
     success : function()
     {
         alert("connected");
     }
     error : function()
     {
         alert("failed");
     }
});
```

What I'm trying to do is see if i can actually access the website (basically check if it is up or not / check my internet connectivity) and if I can I'd like to return an alert saying I am connected. Anyone know why the above code doesnt work? Thanks

Comment: Is it just not returning anything or is there an error in the console. I believe `async` was deprecated.

Comment: Try specifying the dataType as well. You may be returning something it doesn't know how to handle.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier  I got this as an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you have messing the comma :)

```
success : function()
     {
         alert("connected");
     },
     error : function()
     {
         alert("failed");
     }
```

try to copy and paste here your console log

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: you have added the comma ?

Comment: Yes, but I have a slight question. Why does this not run if I am in the offline cached version?

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Check your browser console, It seems like there is a syntax error as *`Splinky`* said in his answer.

**2)** You can't make `cross-domain` requests! If your site (and code) is under `alpha.mywebsite.com` and you want to make the ajax call (`GET`) to another page inside `alpha.mywebsite.com`, then everything will work, otherwise not and you will see an error related to some policy at `browser` console.

So, will be good to know what is happening (exactly) by checking the `browser` console first of all, then `1` or `2` could be your problem.

Comment: Hey Oscar, just a quick question. Why does this ajax function not run while I am in the offline cached mode?

Answer (score 1):

If that JavaScript code is not being executed in the "http://alpha.mywebsite.com" domain (for example, in your PC's local web server), it's probably failing because the browser is blocking the request. If that's the case, you might want to take a look at [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

This happens when you're requesting a resource from a different domain via the `XMLHttpRequest` object and that domain hasn't allowed cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) via the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: Hey Meryovi, would you be able to explain to me why the function does not run while I am in an offline cached mode?

Comment: That code is in the same server your test.html page is or in your local web server?